# How do you spell Marry Kozakura's name in English?

Tags: kagerou-project

I've been using "Marry" up until now, but it just occurred to me that I don't know for sure if that's the best choice.

As I understand it, the spelling of her name varies a lot across translations. I've seen "Marry", "Mary", and "Marie" being used. Also, in Japanese, her given name is 茉莉, which I've seen get read as both まり and マリー.

So, is there a particular spelling that is more commonly used or more official than the others? Or are they about the same? How do the translators' choices for her name compare between the songs, the manga, the light novel, the anime, and other supplementary material?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [official website](https://www.mekakucityactors.com/) for Mekakucity Actors, Marry is a valid Romanized spelling of her name. Usually when there is discrepancy over how a name is Romanized across different media it is because there is no single official version, or the else the spelling changed over time, or else there just wasn't much care taken in localizing the name (either because the translators weren't familiar with the origin or target language, or because different translators had different opinions and were allowed to do what they wanted).

So the answer to your question is that any / all spellings in official media are valid, with the more recent ones probably being the "most official". When it comes to names translations and readings are much less cut and dry. Even the Japanese spelling マリー is a non-standard way of reading the kanji in her name, which is also fairly common with Japanese names.